# Neural network optimization algorithm : ValueError:optimizer got an empty parameter list

Tags: python, optimization, parameters, neural-network

Optuna is used to implement the optimization of the combination of neural network algorithms and learning coefficients.

I have set up a candidate region for optimizer and tried to train it, but I get an error message that the parameter list is empty.

```
class Net(pl.LightningModule):

    def __init__(self, n_layers=1, n_mid=10, lr=0.01):
        super().__init__()

        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.n_mid = n_mid
        self.lr = lr
        
        self.layers = nn.Sequential()

    def forward(self, x):
        h = self.layers(x)
        return h

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        self.log('train_loss', loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log('train_acc', accuracy(y.softmax(dim=-1), t), on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        self.log('val_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log('val_acc', accuracy(y.softmax(dim=-1), t), on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        return loss

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        self.log('test_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log('test_acc', accuracy(y.softmax(dim=-1), t), on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(self.parameters(), lr=self.lr)
        return optimizer

    def objective(self, trial):

        optimizer = trial.suggest_categorical('optimizer', ['SGD', 'Adagrad', 'RMSprop', 'Adadelta', 'Adam', 'AdamW'])
        lr = trial.suggest_loguniform('lr', 1e-5, 1e-1)

        optimizer = getattr(torch.optim, optimizer)(self.parameters(), lr=self.lr)

        pl.seed_everything(0)
        net = Net(optimizer, lr)
        trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=10, gpus=1, deterministic=True, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc')])
        trainer.fit(net, train_loader, val_loader)
        result = trainer.callback_metrics['val_acc']

        return result

sampler = optuna.samplers.TPESampler(seed=0)

study = optuna.create_study(sampler=sampler, direction='maximize') 

study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100)
```

**ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list**

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
optimizer = getattr(torch.optim, optimizer)(self.parameters(), lr=self.lr)
```

This part caused the error.
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/error-optimizer-got-an-empty-parameter-list/1501
torch.optim expects Module.parameters object, but it seems like you fed empty variable to torch.optim.
take a look at this example.
https://github.com/DaikiOnodera/optuna-examples/blob/main/pytorch/pytorch_lightning_simple.py

Comment: Thank you very much answer to me!
I fixed code.
But, new error has occurred...